# Strange behavior of pydev with unicode

Tags: python, pydev

I'm trying to fix a bug in a python project. When the client enter some utf8 characters like 'é' into a program written with PyQt, there is an error . The client execute the program in console mode (activate the virtualenv and execute the script main.py)
But when I run the same program under Eclipse and Pydev, I can not reproduce the problem (everything is ok). Also I'm sure that Eclipse use the same virtualenv as the client.
How could it be possible that running the program inside Eclipse could be different than running in a command line?
Thanks,

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: this is the code that catch the error        `except ValueError:
                QMessageBox.warning(self, "Value Error", "Error in the type of the value", buttons=QMessageBox.Ok)`

Comment: If this is the Windows command line, Windows doesn't use utf-8. It has some code page that it converts every character into.

Comment: No I'm running it on Debian, but I have tried to print manually the traceback wich is `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hnng/workspace/dxp_valoris/valoris_super/tables.py", line 202, in udpateValues
    setattr(elem, fieldName_id, unicode(str(widget.toPlainText())))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`
`

Comment: pydev sets the default encoding to "utf8" ... consoles are typically ascii  you will need to do something like `user_value = user_value.decode('utf8')` or something along those lines ... pydev is trying to be helpful by displaying utf8 characters... but its really frusterating when it does not mirror the real world ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, there are a few things going on. First, `toPlainText` already returns a unicode object. So the problem is here:

```
>>> str("é")
'\x82'
>>> unicode(str("é"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 0: ordinal
not in range(128)
```

According to http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html, "if you leave off the encoding argument, the ASCII encoding is used for the conversion, so characters greater than 127 will be treated as errors".

So if you still need to encode, then add an encoding[1](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) argument, like:

```
>>> unicode(str("é"), 'latin_1')
u'\x82'
```